# Probability of A given B if we don't know the probability of B

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This is a fairly basic question, but I'm not exactly sure what the answer to it is:

If  $P(A)=0.9$  , $P(B \mid A)=0.8$ and $P(B \mid A^C)=0.7$,   what is the probability of $P(A \mid B)$ ?

I can't plug it into the standard formula for conditional probability since $P(B)$ is not known. My initial thought was that the probability of A given B is equal to the probability of A ($0.9$) because the probability of A is seemingly unaffected by the occurrence of B. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: How do you see that the "probability of A is seemingly unaffected by the occurrence of B"?

Comment: @miracle173 It seems like based on what we know, A occurs with probability 0.9 regardless of what happens with B - that's my intuition speaking.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand now. Since the dependence of events is a symmetric relation, B being affected by A implies A being affected by B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A^{C})$$ $$=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^{C})P(A^{C})$$ $$=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^{C})[1-P(A)].$$

Comment: Taking this on to $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(B\mid A)P(A)}{P(B\mid A)P(A)+P(B \mid A^{C})[1-P(A)]}$ or $P(A_i\mid B)=\frac{P(B\mid A_i)P(A_i)}{\sum_j P(B\mid A_j)P(A_j)}$ is the essence of Bayes Theorem.